# Как ускорить работу с базой данных Firebird

Tags: android, kotlin, firebird

Есть база данных, там, допустим, таблица с парой сотен строк. Когда я открываю приложение, оно последовательно считывает все данные из этих таблиц, создает класс и выводит его в ListView. Вопрос в следующем, когда я начинаю проходить по базе, это занимает у меня больше минуты, каким образом можно увеличить скорость работы с базой, если строк там может быть больше десятка тысяч?

Код прохода по бд:

```
fun getPlatform(): Array<Platform> {
    val connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, getConnectionProperties())
    val statement: Statement = connection.createStatement()
    val getPlatforms = "select*from platform"
    val response:ResultSet = statement.executeQuery(getPlatforms)
    val PlatformArray:MutableList<Platform> = arrayListOf()
    while(response.next()){
        val id = response.getInt(1) 

        ///здесь значения десяти столбиков записываются в переменные///
        
        val tempPlatform = Platform(...)
        PlatformArray.add(tempPlatform)
    }
    connection.close()
    return PlatformArray.toTypedArray()
}
```

Comment: Грузите порциями. `select first 10 skip 20 from platform`. Отлично с этим поможет Paging Library (и RecyclerView тоже)...

Comment: Так, хорошо, со списком понял, а если у меня на карте каждый элемент имеет свое местоположение? Может и тут можно как то извернуться

Comment: Не совсем понятно о какой карте идет речь, либо уточните вопрос, либо задайте новый.

Comment: @YuraIvanov ну, это наверное уже другой вопрос